# How can I get the run date and time generated by Hydra?

Tags: python-3.x, fb-hydra

I use [hydra](https://hydra.cc/) in a Python project. My yaml configuration file contains these lines:

```yaml
now_dir: ${now:%Y-%m-%d}/${now:%H-%M-%S}
hydra:
  run:
    dir: ./hydra_outputs/${now_dir}
```

In my code I want to get the date and time used by hydra to create its output folder structure. It would be perfect if hydra had a built-in function that could return a `str` or a `Datetime` object containing the date generated from `${now:%Y-%m-%d}/${now:%H-%M-%S}`.

If not, I can still parse the current path set by hydra (which I can get with `os.getcwd()`) or use the information in the `Dictconfig` created by hydra from the yaml above, but it would be less convenient.

Answer (score 1):

What about using just a plain yaml anchor?

```
now_dir: &nowdir ${now:%Y-%m-%d}/${now:%H-%M-%S}
```

You will able to use the value `*nowdir` later in the .yaml file.

Comment: that's a good way to "copy/paste" a value in a yaml file. But it does not solve my problem since I want to get this information in my python code. I'm seeking for a function that I could use in my code like `hydra.utils.get_cwd()`

Answer (score 0):

So the best way I found is to get the date from the path that hydra created with a regex:

```py
>>> import re
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> path
'hydra_outputs/2021-07-09/16-25-37/.hydra'
>>> match = re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}', path)
>>> datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%Y-%m-%d/%H-%M-%S')
datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 9, 16, 25, 37)
```

I leave the question open in case someone have a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

See the docs on [Accessing the Hydra config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69449335/how-can-i-get-the-run-date-and-time-generated-by-hydra).

As of Hydra version 1.1, your options include:

### 1) In your config, using the hydra resolver:

```yaml
output_dir: ${hydra:run.dir}
```

Note the colon inside the brackets in the above yaml code: this is a call to a [custom resolver](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.1_branch/usage.html#resolvers) named "hydra".

In your python code, you'd be able to access this value via the `output_dir` key on your main function's config:

```py
@hydra.main()
def my_app(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
    print(cfg.output_dir)
```

### 2) In your code, using the HydraConfig singleton:

```py
from hydra.core.hydra_config import HydraConfig

@hydra.main()
def my_app(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
    print(HydraConfig.get().run.dir)
```

For consistent results, make sure that your access to the HydraConfig singleton happens within the bounds of your `@hydra.main`-decorated function.